# Variable-sized object may not be initialized

Tags: c

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: при попытке инициализации массива, размер которого указывется при помощи переменной, с последующим заполнением нулями, компилятор выдает ошибку:

> variable-sized object may not be initialized

Фрагмент кода:

```
const int size = 20;
int a[size] = {0};
```

С чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Именно с тем, что написал компилятор. Массивы VLA не поддерживают никаких инициализаторов в объявлениях. Хотите обнулить VLA-массив - объявляйте его без инициализатора, а затем обнуляйте сами отдельно. Циклом, или `memset`, или как вам больше нравится

```
const int size = 20;
int a[size];
memset(a, 0, sizeof a);
```

В языке С по этой причине для объявления именованных целочисленных констант в общем случае не рекомендуется использовать `const` объявления. Используйте `#define` или `enum`.